# Listview блокировка нажатий пунктов

Tags: android, listview, listener

Подскажите как при выборе одного какого то элемента в `listview` (в методе `setOnItemClickListener`), остальные пункты сделать не кликабельными.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите флаг, который будет определять, надо ли выполнять действия по клику. И если `флаг == true`, делать `return` из `onItemClick()`. А устанавливать флаг в true тогда, когда ненужно, чтобы элементы кликались

Comment: Может есть ссылка на пример?

Comment: @АндрейЕровенков, нету ссылки. реализация зависит от вашего кода.